# Regex to match chunks of data

Tags: regex

Given something like this - where the string contains line breaks and carriage returns; I added the character in to the example for brevity:

```
AB01 88 99 10
\nHH01 123 123
\nHH02 123 123
\nHH03 123 123
\nXX10 88 99 10
\nHH01 456 789
\nHH02 456 789
\nHH03 456 789
\nXX10 99 10 11
```

I am trying to extract groups of HH01 to HH03

I'm expecting a result like this.

```
groups = [
        "HH01 123 123\nHH02 123 123\nHH03 123 123",
        "HH01 456 789\nHH02 456 789\nHH03 456 789"
         ]
```

I'm trying to extract it with regular expressions, though am not fully understanding what I'm doing.

My expression looks like this: `/HH01(.*)HH03/`

I can't figure out how to handle the line breaks. I've tried `/HH01(.*)HH03/m` too.

Can anybody help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try [`HH01(?:[\s\S]*?)HH03.*`](https://regex101.com/r/hiYlfl/1) or enable `s` flag i.e `HH01(?s:.*?)HH03.*`. BTW what is `\m`?

Comment: Why are you expecting `HH01 123 123\nHH....` but not `\nHH01 123 123\nHH....` ?

Comment: I'll give that a go right now. and \m was a typo (correcting now) i saw it on regexr.com when selecting flags

Comment: @revo - works like a charm! Would you mind, if you have time, giving a little brief explanation on those flags? I'll glady mark it as the answer. And thank you !

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - no reason at this time,

Comment: `m` (`MULTILINE`) flag (in most flavors) unlike its name doesn't have any thing to do with matching multi-line strings. It's `s` (`DOTALL`) which makes `.` to match a line terminator character causing `.*` to go beyond one line.

Comment: I'd say it's a duplicate. Let me close with the right topic.

Comment: @revo Congratulations on the regex gold badge.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you!